# Can a US citizen living abroad on a long stay visa in France travel to the UK (by train) without a passport?

Tags: visas, usa, uk, france, blue-card

I am a US citizen with a valid US passport, and have a long stay visa for France. I'm getting my residence card next Month, as part of my EU blue card. Is it possible to take the Paris <-> London train using my global entry ID card (or something else) and not bring my passport?

The reason I ask is that I need to renew my passport, since it expires soon-ish, and the timing of this potential trip is right in the window of when the consulate may still have it and be processing it.

Comment: As I recall, Global Entry applies only to certain countries that neighbor the USA, e. g. the Bahamas and Canada.

Comment: @CarlF To use it to go through customs, yes, but I was thinking of it as just an alternate ID if I don't have my passport, like a DL or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need your passport https://www.gov.uk/uk-border-control/before-you-leave-for-the-uk As a US citizen, residence in another EU country doesn’t give you the right to enter the UK without your passport.